# Javascriptの関数定義の表記方法について質問させて頂きます。

Tags: javascript

```
function [name]([param1[, param2[, ..., paramN]]]) {
   statements
}
```

の引数部分`([param1[, param2[, ..., paramN]]])`を理解できず悩んでいます。

この部分を`param1,param2,・・・,paramN`と表現しないのはなぜなのでしょうか。

もしかして、`[param1[, param2[, ..., paramN]]]`と`param1,param2,・・・paramN`は別物なのでしょうか。

初心者のためか2週間必死にWebを探し続けましたが
納得できる情報にたどり着けませんでしたので
質問をさせて頂く事に致しました。

どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: インラインという機能について理解不足でした。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Javascriptの関数定義の表記** ではなく、**説明のための表記**です。具体的には `[]` は省略可能であることを表す記号です。文書毎に微妙に表記が異なることがあるため、詳しくは参照された文書を確認ください。書籍であれば、本文より前に「本書での表記」等の見出しで説明されているはずです。
また`...`についても同様にJavaScriptの構文ではなく、同様の手順で繰り返されることを表す記号でしかありません。（蛇足ですが、これとは別に最新のJavaScriptでは`...restParameters`という表記も導入されています）

Comment: 大変ありがとうございました。モヤモヤがかなりスッキリ致しました。また、restParametersという表記についてもご教授頂きありがとうございました。こちらは全く知りませんでした。勉強を続けます。ありがとうございました。